# Struct is not a type when passed as a parameter to a function in a separate package

Tags: go

I'm making a JSON validation function and I'm trying to implement it. However I'm having issues with my structs when I try to import them as a parameter to my validation function, which is in another package.

The reason to why it's in another package is because a universal validation function that I will call in different route files, so I can't actually have any structs inside that package, they must be imported and defined in the route file.

```
type UsersJSON struct {
    Users struct {
        Put []UserJSON `json:"PUT"`
    } `json:"users"`
}

type UserJSON struct {
    display_name     string `json:"display_name"`
    username        string `json:"username"`
    email           string `json:"email"`
    password        string `json:"password"`
}

func MyFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    errors, _ := schema.Validate(data, r, UsersJSON)
}

func Validate(schemaHelper interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    file, err := os.Open("config/schema/schema.json")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer file.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(file)

    var helpers schemaHelper // this is the error

    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &helpers)
    fmt.Printf("%v", helpers)
}
```

My JSON schema looks like this:

```
{
    "users": {
        "PUT": {
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make this method work because it makes automating validation much easier and faster.

This doesn't compile and gives the error `schemaHelper is not a type`

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to declare a variable called `helpers`, of type `schemaHelper`, but (at least within the code shown) you have not defined any type called `schemaHelper`. You have a *variable* called `schemaHelper`. You can't use a type as a variable, or a variable as a type. You'd have to call `Validate` by passing an *instance* of `UsersJSON`, which you could then unmarshal the JSON into directly. It seems like what you're likely looking for is instead something like this:

```
func MyFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var unmarshaled UsersJSON
    errors, _ := schema.Validate(&unmarshaled)
}

func Validate(schemaHelper interface{}) (error) {
    file, err := os.Open("config/schema/schema.json")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer file.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(file)

    return json.Unmarshal(byteValue, schemaHelper)
}
```

This would unmarshal the JSON into the variable `schemaHelper` (whatever type it might be), for the caller to then use as it sees fit. Note that this is a rough best guess, because in your question the call to `Validate` passes 3 parameters but the function definition given only accepts 1 parameter.

However, I don't think this does "validation" in the way that you think it does based on the question. It only validates that the JSON is *syntactically valid*, not that it has any relation to the `struct` you pass in - it could have fields that aren't defined in the struct, it could be missing fields that are defined, and it will not return any errors.

Lastly, the type `UsersJSON` has no exported fields (all the fields begin with a lower-case letter, making them unexported/private), so nothing will be unmarshaled into it no matter what. `encoding/json` can only unmarshal into exported fields.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's really helpful. I'm just wondering though, as seen in my question I had a variable, but in your answer it is missing. I need it so I can loop the json file, etc. Is that still possible?

Comment: The only variable I removed was `helpers` because its definition was mistaken. If you want to use the unmarshalled JSON, it's in the `schemaHelper` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `schemaHelper` is not a type. It is in fact, a function variable of type `interface{}`, as you have declared in the function `Validate`.